# Is it possible to find the equivalent resistor for this set of resistors using the usual rules for resistors in parallel and series?

Tags: resistors

I have to find the equivalent resistance for this arrangement of resistors. Not sure if I'm missing something obvious or not.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

> Not sure if I'm missing something obvious or not.

It's not obvious until you've met it for the first time.

The 'T' of resistors, the 20Ω and the lower two 10Ω resistors, can be transformed into a delta of resistors between the same nodes by using the [Wye-Delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Y-%CE%94_transform) transform.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fmEU2l.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

\$R_a = \frac{R_1R_2+R_2R_3+R_3R_1}{R_1}\$, and the equivalent equation for Rb and Rc

This will now result in the 5Ω and the top 10Ω resistors having simple single parallel resistors across them, and the rest will be straightforward parallel and series combinations.

There are other ways you could attack the problem. You could start by taking the left triangle of 5Ω, 20Ω and 10Ω and turn those into a 'T'. Or you could take the top triangle of 20, 10 and 10 and make those a 'T'. It might be worth doing all three and comparing the results, just to see that all eventually get to the same answer. You might have to flip between T and delta several times, some routes will be quicker than others. With experience, you'll be able to spot which routes reduce the network more quickly.

Answer (score 3):

> *Is it possible to find the equivalent resistor for this set of
> resistors using the usual rules for resistors in parallel and series?*

No, you need to do more than just that.

Just think about what you see and ask yourself this question; are there any resistors that are unambiguously in series or in parallel. The answer is no hence you need to use circuit theorems for solving the problem.